In what ways can I use the DUP keyword in DDS for the IBMi?
TLDR
In what ways can I define DUP in a DDS file that I haven't tried?
Note: I don't care about the RPG to hook it up. I'm only looking at the Display File definition.
In a perfect world, someone out there knows exactly what I need to get the 0x06 keyword on a field when reading in the results of calling the QDFRTVFD api.
I'll take any suggestions for DDS to try, particularly unusual ones.
At this point, I'm not sure if the api is bugged or the documentation is wrong, or if I'm just missing something.
Background:
I'm working on fixing a bug in a C++ class that calls the QDFRTVFD api ([https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/qdfrtvfd.html) from IBM and parses the returned buffer.
The bug was in a method that handles a particular category of keywords. Basically, we misunderstood the api documentation (or it is just plain wrong), and cast some of the keywords to the wrong size data structure, throwing off our pointer arithmetic.
I am now manually testing each keyword in the affected category to make sure that we're using the correct data structure for each.
Here's the list:
Category 22 (Miscellaneous Field-Level Keywords)
The following table shows the keyword ID that corresponds to miscellaneous field-level keywords. Not all keywords require a structure. There are no structures for keyword IDs X'01', X'02', X'03', X'04', X'05', X'06' and X'07'.



ID
Keyword
ID
Keyword




0x01
PUTRETAIN
0x10
MSGID


0x02
OVRDTA
0x15
ERRMSG


0x03
OVRATR
0x16
ERRMSGID


0x04
BLANKS
0x17
DSPATR(PFLD)


0x05
CHANGE
0x18
DATTIMFMT


0x06
DUP
0x19
DATTIMSEP


0x07
DUP
0x1A
DATE




0x1B
MAPVAL



I have been able to generate all of the above keywords except for 0x06 DUP.
The documentation does not make it clear what the difference between 0x06 and 0x07 is. I can generate a 0x07 by defining the DUP keyword with a Response Indicator.
For example, this field definition gives me 3 category 22 keywords, 0x04, 0x05, and 0x07:
     A            FLD4           5A  B  4 30BLANKS(12) 
     A                                      DUP(04) 
     A                                      CHANGE(06) 

I thought that since some keywords take response indicators and some don't, and because DUP can be defined with and without an indicator, that 0x07 must be DUP with an indicator and 0x06 must be DUP without an indicator. However, when I tried to define a field with DUP with no indicator, the result was no category 22 keyword at all.
For example, if I remove the (04) from the above example, I only get 2 category 22 keywords, not 3.
Here is my current test DDS source. It just defines a bunch of fields with various combinations of keywords. Most are from the above list, but there are some others there as well as I was testing other categories too.
     A                                      REF(SUBFILE3) 
     A                                      DSPSIZ(24 80 *DS3) 
     A                                      PRINT 
     A                                      INDARA 
     A                                      CA03(03 'F3=EXIT') 
     A          R SCRN                      OVERLAY 
     A            FLD1           5   B  3  2CHANGE(41) 
     A                                      PUTRETAIN 
     A  48                                  DSPATR(HI) 
     A                                  2 20'SOMETHING SOMETHING SOMETHING' 
     A                                      PUTRETAIN 
     A            FLD2          15   B  3 50 
     A                                      CHANGE(25) 
     A            FLD3           5Y 0B  4 10BLANKS(10) 
     A  49                                  DSPATR(RI) 
     A                                      CHANGE(15) 
     A                                      PUTRETAIN 
     A            FLD4           5A  B  4 30BLANKS(12) 
     A                                      DUP(04) 
     A                                      CHANGE(06) 
     A            FLD5           5   B  4 50COLOR(BLU) 
     A  50                                  DSPATR(RI) 
     A  51                                  DSPATR(PC) 
     A          R SCRN2                     PUTOVR 
     A            FLD6           6   B  5  2DFT('FOOBAR') 
     A                                      OVRDTA 
     A                                      CHANGE(03) 
     A                                      DUP(09 'comment') 
     A  20        FLD7           5   B  5 20DSPATR(BL) 
     A  21                                  DSPATR(RI) 
     A                                      OVRATR 
     A                                      OVRDTA 
     A                                      DFT('MEH!!') 
     A            FLD8          25   O  5 50MSGID(*NONE) 
     A            FLD9          25   B  6  2CHANGE(47) 
     A  60                                  ERRMSG('TEST1' 60) 
     A  66                                  ERRMSG('TEST2' 66) 
     A  63                                  ERRMSGID(MSG2000 TEST 63) 
     A            FLD10           L  B  7  2DATFMT(*JOB) 
     A                                      CHANGE(72) 
     A            FLD11           T  B  7 20TIMFMT(*EUR) 
     A                                      CHANGE(73) 
     A            FLD12           T  B  7 40TIMFMT(*HMS) TIMSEP('.') 
     A                                      CHANGE(81) 
     A            FLD13           L  B  7 60DATFMT(*DMY) DATSEP('-') 
     A                                      CHANGE(82) 
     A                                  8  2DATE(*SYS) 
     A                                  8 12DATE(*Y) 
     A            FLD14           L     8 24DATFMT(*MDY) DATSEP('/') 
     A                                      MAPVAL(('06/17/95' *BLANK)) 
     A            FLD15         10   B  9  5COLOR(BLU) 
     A  70                                  DSPATR(RI) 
     A  71                                  DSPATR(PC) 
     A                                      OVRDTA 
     A                                      DFT('My value') 
     A            FLD16          5Y 0B  9 25 
     A  65                                  DSPATR(HI) 
     A                                      DSPATR(&PFLD1) 
     A            PFLD1          1A  P 
     A            FLD17          3A  I 10  5DUP 

Some variations I have tried for defining DUP:

As in FLD4 above, no option indicator but with a response indicator (result: 0x07)
As in FLD17 above, no option indicator and no response indicator (result: no keyword)
With an option indicator and a response indicator (result: 0x07)
With an option indicator and no response indicator (result: no keyword)
On a field in a subfile record with response indicator (result: 0x07)
On a field in a subfile record, no response indicator (result: no keyword)
The above fields are character fields. I also tried a numeric, which requires the response indicator (result: 0x07)
Tried setting the USRDSPMGT file-level keyword for System/36 functionality and retrying the above variations again. (result: no change)
Tried the CLRL record level keyword with USRDSPMGT. (result: no change)
Tried setting CHANGE, COMP, RANGE, and VALUE validation keywords with the DUP keyword. (result: no change)
Tried all field data types defined here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=35-valid-entries-display-files
with response indicator. (result: 0x07)
Tried all field data types without response indicator. (result: no keyword)


It could just be an inaccuracy in the documentation. I have found that before in other rarely used parts of the display file docs. Is there a particular reason you need to use the "missing" key?

@jmarkmurphy I just need to make sure that our code is handling that particular keyword correctly. Different keywords have different extended data structures, and the docs are indeed terrible. If we get that keyword showing up on a client's system and we're using the wrong structure, it'll break the pointer arithmetic. I've handled it so it won't crash our application, but it will still fail to parse the data structure.
I'm working on reaching out to IBM directly for clarification, so hopefully I can report back on what I'm missing or if it is bad docs or a bug.

Just a wild guess ... the doc says "See System/36 environment considerations for display files for special considerations when specifying the DUP keyword in files that are used in the System/36 environment."
https://www.ibm.com/docs/pt/i/7.4?topic=files-system36-environment-considerations-display
That page says "The User Display Management (USRDSPMGT) keyword causes the record formats in the display file to function similarly to System/36 SFGR display formats."
Maybe you'll get a different ID for the DUP keyword if you add USRDSPMGT to the keywords.
BTW, kudos on what is probably the best-written stackoverflow post I have ever seen :-)

Thank you so much for your suggestion. I gave the USRDSPMGT keyword a try along with the CLRL keyword mentioned in the USRDSPMGT docs. Unfortunately it didn't make a difference to which keyword id I get.
Based on your suggestion, I also tried pairing DUP with the validation keywords mentioned in the docs. That didn't help either.
I have updated my question to indicate I tried these variations.

This is just a WAG after a brief perusal of the API docs ...
But I noticed a lot of

DUP keyword ... on a numeric field

Have you tried the DUP keyword on a numeric field with and without the indicator?

Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried a basic numeric field, but I to be sure I went back and tried every field data type that is supposed to be valid for display files. I tried them all with and without a response indicator and with and without an option indicator.
The result in all cases was 0x07 if I specify a response indicator. No category 22 keyword at all if I do not specify the indicator.

If you are doing SHIFT-Insert for DUP, can you try SHIFT-Insert on the numpad?
keyboard map
